# Gwt and jsp in same project

Tags: java, jsp, gwt

i was looking for similar title here  but i didn't find much info, so if anyone can provide some example or url or any approach how to do it.

For example: is it possible to call a jsp from a gwt widget?
or communication (server - jsp) in gwt project and so on..
Is there any limitation is using jsp in gwt project?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT compiles down to html+javascript (static files), while JSPs are internally compiled and behave like servlets. You can configure URLs to point to both (via your server config and/or web.xml).

Both GWT and JSP allow you to go to a new URL. In GWT you can use `Window.Location.assign(url)` (this will load new URL and close current GWT app).

Additionally GWT allows you to load data by making XHR calls to URLs: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON.html

So:

1. Yes you can goto JSP pages from GWT app.
2. Yes you can load data provided by JSPs into your GWT app.

Comment: Thanks Peter, like always a good post :) Ok, but actually i don't see any advantage of using JSPs in entire gwt project, what do you think about that??

Comment: JSPs are nice when you need to generate simple HTML or JSON, to be then loaded by your GWT. Personally I use them for OpenID login and return pages.

Answer (score 2):

In any jsp applications actions lead to URLs. The URL can point to a GWT module.

You will find applications which offer a back-end for the administrator in GWT, while the front-end runs in Struts2. [Konakart](http://www.konakart.com) e-shop is such an example.

My impression is that GWT will replace the other frameworks on the long run. Everybody will want Rich Internet Applications very soon.

On the other hand in the early 80's i was thinking that in very few years everybody would be using Unix, which never happened, but Unix did quite well after all...

Comment: I got your point. But how can i compose url pointing gwt ? need any examples .... Thanks Costis for your post.

Comment: I is fairly simple. Write a mini GWT application, something like the ButtonClick default and deploy it to let's say, Tomcat. It will run from a specific URL. The jsp application starts at another. You just neet to define the links that send you from one to the other. Both can connect to the same DB for persistence. You can also use A GWT Plugin if you use Struts2. https://cwiki.apache.org/S2PLUGINS/gwt-plugin-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks Costis, you helped me.